# Azure Mobile Services (push notifications)

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I'm moving my PNS from php to Azure Mobile services. In PHP i had to write a script to read some html page and push the messages to the registered devices every 10 minutes.

How can I do that using Azure Mobile Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but Azure Mobile Services has added [scheduled jobs in the latest release](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/schedule-backend-tasks/). As of right now, I think the quickest interval you can run background jobs every 15 minutes, and even then that's only when you are running your mobile service on a reserved instance.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment you cannot write scheduled jobs (something which would run every X minutes) to run in Azure Mobile Services. I added this as a suggestion to the [Azure Mobile Services UserVoice](http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/3345850-allow-scheduled-tasks-to-be-executed-in-the-backen) to be implemented.